# Dojo - Prevent dijit/popup cancel on escape key press

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have am using dijit/popup to display a dialog widget when a button is clicked. The documentation below describes how to use dijit/popup to control the popup.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/popup.html

The code is as follows:

```
define(["dijit/popup"], function(popup){
...

// wrap the pop-up widget and position it offscreen so
// that it can be measured by the widget’s startup method
popup.moveOffScreen(dropDown);

// if the pop-up has not been started yet, start it now
if(dropDown.startup && !dropDown._started){
    dropDown.startup();
}

// make the pop-up appear around my node
popup.open({
    parent: this,
    popup: dropDown,
    around: this.domNode,
    orient: ["below-centered", "above-centered"],
    onExecute: function(){
        popup.close(dropDown);
    },
    onCancel: function(){
        popup.close(dropDown);
    },
    onClose: function(){
    }
});

...
```

However the default behavior of dijit/popup is to call the onCancel callback function either when the popped up widget signals its cancelled or when the ESC key is pressed:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/popup.html#keyboard-handling

I can see this happening when the ESCape key is pressed however I don't want the dialog to be closed for ESC (or TAB) key press - how can I achieve this? How can I detect when the onCancel callback is executed as a result of the user pressing the Escape key?

Alternatively how can I prevent dijit/popup calling onCancel only when the escape key is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no clean way to do this. What you can do is suppress the escape key event for the popup/dropdown. To do this you must set up a key handler after the popup has been displayed. To do this you need the function name that opens the popup and you need access to the popup itself or its parent. Note that the popup is placed at a random place in the DOM and is not a child of the widget that opens it/drops it. For example the DateTextBox calls the openDropDown function to open its calendar widget and stores it in member dropDown. You can suppress the key event so that the drop down is not closed with the escape key like this:

```
require([
    "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
    "dojo/aspect",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/keys",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(DateTextBox, aspect, on, keys){

    var dateBox = new DateTextBox({});
    aspect.after(dateBox, "openDropDown", function () {
        on(this.dropDown, "keydown", function(event)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == keys.ESCAPE)
            {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
        });
    });
    dateBox.placeAt("datebox");
    dateBox.startup();
});
```

You may need to add an additional function to your popup (or an aspect to an existing function) to expose the popup after it is opened (the equivalent of this.dropDown in the above snippet).

Comment: Thanks I need to test this out in my scenario. I need to ensure the ESC is ignored for the dropped down widget but doesn't prevent propagation for another widget. In my case the ArcGIS Javascript API Draw toolbar uses escape to stop drawing a feature on the map so I would like this to work - and for the popup dialog to remain open.

Comment: You may have to add this logic to the event handler, i.e. after calling stopProgation() stop drawing and then return.

Comment: I tried to do this but I cant seem to prevent the ESC key propagating from the map draw tool, the esri widget seems to prevent it being intercepted by any handler. If when I open the popup I attach a global keydown handler on the window/map/map layers - once I start drawing it still doesnt intercept the key press.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: make sure that this.domNode is regular DIV element. Create onClick listener hooked up to this domNode, to show popup. Popup window created like this will ignore ESC button or user's clicking on the blank space around the popup. You will have to hide it yourself by popup.close(this) from within the popup or popup.close(this.dropDown) from outside.
No need to suppress/override anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - do you have a simple example of this working? In my case I open the popup programmatically. The dialog needs to open either when a button is clicked or when a link on the map is clicked. I tried creating a popup attached directly to a div but I get the error - Object doesn't support property or method 'isLeftToRight' when I try to open the popup